# how to update both parent and child state before render without extra renders in React 15

Tags: reactjs

If I use setState in the child and place a callback in the parent to update the parent state that propagates to child props, then I end up with two render calls.

One for the update to the child state, and one for the prop changing. I can manually use shouldComponentUpdate to ignore the prop change if I want, but the render won't be ready until the state updates.

I know all this can be done easily in react 16-18, but migrating is not simple at the moment.

I am wondering if the solution is to make the child state the source of truth. I can solve all my problems this way, but I thought in react you typically made the parent the source of truth.

Parent Component
Child Component

ChildComponent

```
function = () => {
  this.setState ( {updatedStateProperty}, callback())
}
```

ParentComponent

```
callback = () => {
    this.setState ( {propSentToChild})
}
```

What happens is the child component changes state, then render occurs, then the callback occurs, prompting another render.

I want to either
A. change child state, then have the callback called before render
or
B. update child state, then ignore the parents passed props

I can do B, but I'm unsure whether it is proper form to basically make the child's version of the shared state the source of truth

Comment: I think you'll need to tell us more about how these states are related to make a meaningful recommendation. As you said, the standard approach is to have the parent be the source of truth, but what that typically means is the parent is the *only* one to have the state, and the child just uses its props. So what's the reason you're considering giving them *both* state?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're kind of close. What you really want to do is pass the state to the parent, handle setting the state there, and let the new state trickle down to your child component via props. This is a fairly common pattern for react.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { foo: "bar", bing: "baz" }
  }
  stateUpdater(newState) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, ...newState });
  }
  render() {
    return <Child 
      prop1={this.state.foo} 
      prop2={this.state.baz}
      stateUpdater={this.stateUpdater} 
    />
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.stateUpdater({ foo: 'bazaar' });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      The foo is {this.props.foo} and the baz is {this.props.baz}.
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: so if the child also has state that gets updated at the same time on click, how do you force only a single render the proper way? what you have is almost the example I was trying to explain, except the child does not have any state of its own. I want handleClick to also set a child state property and update the parent while generating a single render for performance reasons

Comment: React renders from top to bottom from wherever the state change happens. There's no way to update a child and then its parent and result in a single render. This is why every intro to react tutorial or explanation always has that line _"find the most common parent, move the state there, and pass it down to the children"_.

Comment: hmm, that's what I thought maybe. but 2 passes on that array is not desirable for performance. so I forced the parent's update of the child to get ignored manually using ShouldComponentUpdate.

felt like a hack and I guess it is a hack

Comment: Its not a hack at all. React tries to do its best, but the react team put methods there for the developer to have the final say on matters of re-rendering. Sometimes you can restructure your data flow and avoid using those methods, but sometimes you have to what's best/easiest and tell react when it doesn't need to re-render.